# How to integrate agora_rtm to a flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, agora-implementation, agora

I am trying to integrate audio and video calling and chat into a flutter using Agora. The backend is built by another team and I only manage the flutter side. I successfully integrated audio and video calling using the API they (the backend team) provided for token generation.

They(the backend team) didn't provide any APIs for token generation for the chat. Can I integrate agora chat with flutter directly without using the custom backend?

Are there any well-written blogs or source codes available for this?

I tried the test app they(the Agora team) provided in the documentation using a temporary token from the console. But I don't know how to do this in a real app.

Answer (score 1):

try this package of [agora_rtm](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm)

Here you will get full documentation and [example](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm/example) also to check.